# Pretty print XML on Spring controller method

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have this method and I want its XML output to be pretty printed.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/models/export/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public HttpEntity<ModelExport> modelExport(@PathVariable("filename") String filename) {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);
    responseHeaders.set(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename="+filename);
    ModelExport model = modelManager.getModel();
    return new HttpEntity<>(model, responseHeaders);
}
```

I found answers for Spring boot which is not my case (plain war). Is there a way how to set the `SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT` for this controller? If not, I will serialize the object to XML myself and return `String`.

Comment: Where is your ModelExport object coming from? Also, is there a reason you would want to pretty print your server response rather than having the response pretty printed client side?

Comment: An origin of the object is irrelevant. It is my decision to return pretty print.